# gstreamer mixer, mix 2 rtsp streams side by side with gst-launch -> timestamping problem occurred

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch-1.0

I am trying to display two streams side by side with gst-launch.

It occurs an error, but the streams are displayed.
`gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage:`

Single rtsp source is displayed correctly.
I tried to the parameter latency to 500, no success.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videomixer name=mix \
    sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
    sink_1::xpos=640   sink_1::ypos=0 \
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.9.20:554/axis-media/media.amp user-id=username user-pw=password latency=150 \
! decodebin max-size-time=30000000000 \
! videoconvert ! videoscale \
! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 \
! mix.sink_1 \
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.9.24:554/axis-media/media.amp user-id=username user-pw=password latency=150 \
! decodebin max-size-time=30000000000 \
! videoconvert ! videoscale \
! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 \
! mix.sink_2 \
mix. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I want to create a mosaic of four rtsp streams.

Please give me help in resolving the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use:

````
mix. ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false```
````